# arcp.Statistics_analysis error 000800

Tags: arcpy, statistics, error-000800

I'm trying to use arcpy.Statistics_analysis using a feature layer as the input and a long int field ("MaxOID5" for the field summary so I can get the max value.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\data\mydata.gdb"

fc = "airplanes"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "fc_layer")

arcpy.Statistics_analysis("fc_layer", "Max_Table", "MaxOID5", "MAX")
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of SUM | MEAN | MIN | MAX | RANGE | STD | COUNT | FIRST | LAST.
```

The help on the error says that "The keyword used is not a member of the list of acceptable keywords" but I'm choosing it directly from the auto generate parameters in the arcmap python command window.

Comment: Run from gui, copy as Python script from Results window and paste to your script. Something is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your third input. Try:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("fc_layer", "Max_Table", [["MaxOID5", "MAX"]], "")
```

Comment: That did it. I had tried it with single brackets around the 3rd and 4th params but got the same result. Thanks!